# How to get item type and members from list of object?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
while (myReader.Read())
{
   string arrKablan = myReader["arrK_Title"].ToString();
   string arrTotal = myReader["arrTotal"].ToString();
   string _title = myReader["MF_Title"].ToString();
   string _path = myReader["MF_Path"].ToString();
   int _level = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["MF_Level"].ToString());

   list.Add(new { title = _title, path = _path, kablanim = arrKablan, total = arrTotal, level = _level });
}
```

I need to select just items where level == 1

i tried

```
list = list.where(item => item.level == 1);
```

but i get an error

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'level' and no extension method 'level' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

i know that the compiler can get the type so he can know what it is "level".
how can i achieve this kind of select, without to define a class ?

Comment: The real question would be why don't you *want* to define a type?

Comment: how interface will help me here?\

Comment: Just edited the comment. Forget about interfaces for now. Otherwise we could go too far elaborating on decorator / wrapper pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why you don't just make a concrete class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    // etc, etc
}
```

Then

```
List<Foo> list = new List<Foo>();

while (myReader.Read())
{
   string arrKablan = myReader["arrK_Title"].ToString();
   string arrTotal = myReader["arrTotal"].ToString();
   string _title = myReader["MF_Title"].ToString();
   string _path = myReader["MF_Path"].ToString();
   int _level = Convert.ToInt32(myReader["MF_Level"].ToString());

   list.Add(new Foo { Title = _title, Path = _path, /* etc, etc */ });
}
```

then you call becomes

```
list = list.Where(item => item.Level == 1).ToList();
```

(Note the additional `ToList` call required to make the `list` assignment valid)

Answer (score 4):

You have two ways of fixing this:

1. Use a `List<dynamic>` instead of a `List<object>`. This will disable type checks. Drawback: This will disable type checks. :-)
2. Let the compiler infer the correct type of your list. To do this, have your data layer return a `DataTable` instead of a `DataReader` and then use LINQ to create the list:

   ```
   var myList = (from drow in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                 select new {
                     kablanim = drow["arrK_Title"].ToString(),
                     total = drow["arrTotal"].ToString(),
                     ...
                 }).ToList();
   ```

Comment: this is the best answer, but i think that i will use @dav_i answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, you can also do this. Create a function to get a value from any object using reflection:

```
private T GetValue<T>(object obj, string property)
{
    return (T)obj.GetType()
                 .GetProperties()
                 .Single(p => p.Name == property)
                 .GetValue(obj);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
var filteredList = list.Where(item => GetValue<int>(item, "level") == 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get value of a property on anonymous class like this:

```
        var anon = new { Level = "level", Time = DateTime.Now };
        Type type = anon.GetType();

        var props = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.Name == "Level")
            {
                var x =propertyInfo.GetValue(anon);

            }
        }
```

I'm not sure if it is the best way to achieve that, but it is certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding object of anonymous class to the list. You can refer to this anonymous class field only inside the method you've defined it in and you should probably avoid adding it to the list, because there is now other way other then reflection or dynamic to access field of theese objects.

For example, you can access one of the elements like this:
var list = new List();

```
    list.Add(new { field1 = "a", field2 = 2 });
    list.Add(new { field1 = "b", field2 = 3 });
    list.Add(new { field1 = "c", field2 = 4 });

    dynamic o = list[1];

    Console.WriteLine(o.field1);
    Console.WriteLine(o.field2);
```

But you should be aware, that dynamic feature has a big overhead on every member access.

If you really want to use lambdas, you can rewrite

```
list = list.where(item => item.level == 1);
```

like this

```
var filtered = list.Where(item =>
{
    dynamic ditem = item;
    return ditem.Level == 1;
});
```

but this is a bad approach.

The other approach is to use reflection and rewrite this lambda like this

```
var filtered = list.Where(item =>
{
    var field = item.GetType().GetField("level");
    return (int)field.GetValue(item) == 1; 
});
```

This is better than using dynamic because it has a smaller overhead, but can still be very costly.

Also it would probably be better to cache FieldInfo object outside of loop if your anonymous objects have same type. It can be done like this

```
var field = list.First().GetType().GetField("level");
var filtered = list.Where(item => (int)field.GetValue(item) == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons, Linq depends on metadata being available *at compile time*. By explicitly declaring `List<object>` you have typed the elements of this list as `object` which does not have a member `level`.

If you want to use Linq like this you have two options.

1. Declare a class with a level member and use it to type the collection
2. Declare an interface with a level member and use it to cast in the lambda expression

Option 1 is the preferred approach. Normally Linq is used with a database and the classes are generated by Visual Studio directly from the database. This is why nobody complains about the need for classes to supply metadata.

Answer (score -1):

The following line creates anonymous class.

```
new { title = _title, path = _path, kablanim = arrKablan, total = arrTotal, level = _level });
```

You can't cast then your objects to anything meaningfull.
Objects don't have those properties.
You have to create a class by your own and use it.

Comment: i know, but it's a class that i will use just one time so i prefer to use anonymous  type.

Comment: You checked as answer completely the same thing I've told you and my answer has minuses, very funny :)

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't minus you :)